# Indention error not making sense - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, nested-loops

I keep getting an indention error when I'm trying to nest this for loop and I don't really understand why. It runs when I un-nest it to the same level as the "for l in searchlines[i-3:i+3]:" I'm just learning so I understand it might not be the most concise code. Thanks for your time.

```
    ne=pd.DataFrame()

    for word in keywordList:    
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
          if word in line:
            for l in searchlines[i-3:i+3]: oFile.write(fileName + delim + word + delim +str(i) + delim +str(l)) ## prints Unused MidFile for Reference
    ### Creates normal case line for Named Entity recognition & all Lower Case line for flagging keywords
            #normalCaseLine = str(searchlines[i-3] + searchlines[i-2] + searchlines[i-1] + searchlines[i] + searchlines[i+1] + searchlines[i+2]  + searchlines[i+3]).replace('\n','  ')
            normalCaseLine = searchlines[i-3].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i].rstrip('\n')  + searchlines[i+1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+3].rstrip('\n')
            lowerCaseLine = normalCaseLine.lower()
            result = dict((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(sorted(lowerCaseLine.split())))
    ### Get Detail Keywords
            cleanResult = {word: result[word] for word in result if word in detailKeywordList}
            cleanNormLine = normalCaseLine.replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x96',' ').replace('\x95',' ')
    ### Enter here if we need to seperate words ex. Tech Keywords

            ner_output = st.tag(str(cleanNormLine).split())
            chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""
    ERROR IS HERE!!
                    for i, word_pos in enumerate(ner_output):
                               word, pos = word_pos
                               if pos in ['PERSON', 'ORGANIZATION', 'LOCATION','DATE','MONEY'] and pos == prev_tag:
                                   chunked[-1]+=word_pos
                               else:
                                              chunked.append(word_pos)
                                              prev_tag = pos

            clean_chunkedd = [tuple([" ".join(wordpos[::2]), wordpos[-1]]) if len(wordpos)!=2 else wordpos for wordpos in chunked]

    ### Write Results to Combined file
            midFile.write(fileName+'-'+str(i)+delim+word+delim+str(cleanNormLine)+delim+str(str(cleanResult).split(','))+'\n')
    ### Create NER DataFramez

            nerTagDF =  DataFrame(clean_chunkedd, columns = ['Word','Classification'])
            nerTagDF['File_Name'] = fileName
            nerTagDF['Line Key'] = str(i)
            ne = ne.append(nerTagDF) 

    oFile.close()
    midFile.close()
```

Comment: Sorry but your code is a mess, it's clear without having to read all the lines that the indentation is inconsistent and not at the same depth for each control point. For instance immediately: `for word in keywordList:    
        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
          if word in line:` you have 4 spaces on the first block indentation but then 2 spaces for the subsequent ones and this continues throughout the rest of your code

Comment: Yep, not to mention, that it's indentation error and not indention :) Just rewrite/copy-paste it in new window/tab/file line by line.

Comment: Each layer of indentation should be 4 spaces. Just looking at that, that section looks like it's more than 4, possibly 8 or more.

Comment: Erm, you get an `IndentationError: unexpected indent` because it doesn't make sense to indent the code there. Correct indentation is _vital_ in Python.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm learning, I know it's not very clear - the only way to get better is for me to mess up and try!

Answer (score 1):

a extra slight tab space is given near the error message

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

"""
Created on Tue Aug 08 18:48:40 2017

@author: user
"""

ne=pd.DataFrame()

```
for word in keywordList:    
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
      if word in line:
        for l in searchlines[i-3:i+3]: oFile.write(fileName + delim + word + delim +str(i) + delim +str(l)) ## prints Unused MidFile for Reference
### Creates normal case line for Named Entity recognition & all Lower Case line for flagging keywords
        #normalCaseLine = str(searchlines[i-3] + searchlines[i-2] + searchlines[i-1] + searchlines[i] + searchlines[i+1] + searchlines[i+2]  + searchlines[i+3]).replace('\n','  ')
        normalCaseLine = searchlines[i-3].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i].rstrip('\n')  + searchlines[i+1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+3].rstrip('\n')
        lowerCaseLine = normalCaseLine.lower()
        result = dict((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(sorted(lowerCaseLine.split())))
### Get Detail Keywords
        cleanResult = {word: result[word] for word in result if word in detailKeywordList}
        cleanNormLine = normalCaseLine.replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x96',' ').replace('\x95',' ')
### Enter here if we need to seperate words ex. Tech Keywords

        ner_output = st.tag(str(cleanNormLine).split())
        chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""
#ERROR IS HERE!!
                for i, word_pos in enumerate(ner_output):
                    word, pos = word_pos
                    if pos in ['PERSON', 'ORGANIZATION', 'LOCATION','DATE','MONEY'] and pos == prev_tag:
                        chunked[-1]+=word_pos
                    else:
                        chunked.append(word_pos)
                        prev_tag = pos

        clean_chunkedd = [tuple([" ".join(wordpos[::2]), wordpos[-1]]) if len(wordpos)!=2 else wordpos for wordpos in chunked]

### Write Results to Combined file
        midFile.write(fileName+'-'+str(i)+delim+word+delim+str(cleanNormLine)+delim+str(str(cleanResult).split(','))+'\n')
### Create NER DataFramez

        nerTagDF =  DataFrame(clean_chunkedd, columns = ['Word','Classification'])
        nerTagDF['File_Name'] = fileName
        nerTagDF['Line Key'] = str(i)
        ne = ne.append(nerTagDF) 

oFile.close()
midFile.close()
```

please check the code... hope it solves your issue...

Answer (score 0):

Your `for` loop is not nested in anything. In Python, one place you use indentations is when a chunk of your code is defined within some scope, such as within a `while` or `for` loop, in an `if` statement, or when defining some function, for example.

Your for loop is indented after `chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""`, which is simply a standalone statement. Therefore, you need to un-indent your loop until it matches the indentation of the surrounding code. That's probably the most general way I can put it.

Answer (score 0):

Clean up your code please. Looks like the error is your line right after the error message:

```
...
chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""
ERROR IS HERE!!
                for i, word_pos in enumerate(ner_output):
...
```

Why is that for loop line so over indented? It should look like this:

```
chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""
# ERROR IS HERE!!
for i, word_pos in enumerate(ner_output):
    # and then pick it up at this indentation
```

Your indentation is inconsistent though. Look here, toward the beginning:

```
1    for word in keywordList:    
2        for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
3          if word in line:
4            for l in searchlines[i-3:i+3]: oFile.write(fileName + delim + word + delim +str(i) + delim +str(l)) ## prints Unused MidFile for Reference
5    ### Creates normal case line for Named Entity recognition & all Lower Case line for flagging keywords
6            #normalCaseLine = str(searchlines[i-3] + searchlines[i-2] + searchlines[i-1] + searchlines[i] + searchlines[i+1] + searchlines[i+2]  + searchlines[i+3]).replace('\n','  ')
7            normalCaseLine = searchlines[
```

Let's go through this line-by-line: line 1 is indented four spaces. That means every indent from here on out should be a multiple of four. Line 2: also four spaces, so far so good. Line three: only two spaces indented from line 2: not good. Should be four spaces more indented than line 2. Line 4: again, two spaces. And you should break it into two lines, maybe even three with the comment on its own line. The `for(...):`, then `oFile.write(...` on a different line with a four-space indent. Lines 6 and 7 look like they should be indented because line 4 is confusing. Line 5, even though it's a comment, should be indented further to match the previous line, unless the previous line is the `for(...):` line, in which case it should be indented four more than that.

Comment: If you found it useful, please feel free to upvote, and accept the answer if it solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

When you first use Python, indentation errors are usual.

What I recomment is to either use only tabulations to indent your code
or spaces.
Because at compile time, python compiler can't deal with a mixture of both.

I didn't check your code, but it is not readable. 
You might want to use an editor with PEP8 Autoformat rules or reformat the code yourself.

Here is a compilable version of your code :

```
ne=pd.DataFrame()

for word in keywordList:    
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if word in line:
            for l in searchlines[i-3:i+3]: 
                oFile.write(fileName + delim + word + delim +str(i) + delim +str(l)) 
                ## prints Unused MidFile for Reference
                ### Creates normal case line for Named Entity recognition & all Lower Case line for flagging keywords
                #normalCaseLine = str(searchlines[i-3] + searchlines[i-2] + searchlines[i-1] + searchlines[i] + searchlines[i+1] + searchlines[i+2]  + searchlines[i+3]).replace('\n','  ')
                normalCaseLine = searchlines[i-3].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-1].rstrip('\n') + \
                    searchlines[i].rstrip('\n')  + searchlines[i+1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+2].rstrip('\n') + \
                    searchlines[i+3].rstrip('\n')
                lowerCaseLine = normalCaseLine.lower()
                result = dict((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(sorted(lowerCaseLine.split())))
                ### Get Detail Keywords
                cleanResult = {word: result[word] for word in result if word in detailKeywordList}
                cleanNormLine = normalCaseLine.replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x96',' ').replace('\x95',' ')
                ### Enter here if we need to seperate words ex. Tech Keywords

                ner_output = st.tag(str(cleanNormLine).split())
                chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""
                for i, word_pos in enumerate(ner_output):
                    word, pos = word_pos
                    if pos in ['PERSON', 'ORGANIZATION', 'LOCATION','DATE','MONEY'] and pos == prev_tag:
                        chunked[-1]+=word_pos
                    else:
                        chunked.append(word_pos)
                        prev_tag = pos

                clean_chunkedd = [tuple([" ".join(wordpos[::2]), wordpos[-1]]) if len(wordpos)!=2 else wordpos for wordpos in chunked]

        ### Write Results to Combined file
        midFile.write(fileName+'-'+str(i)+delim+word+delim+str(cleanNormLine)+delim+str(str(cleanResult).split(','))+'\n')
        ### Create NER DataFramez

        nerTagDF =  DataFrame(clean_chunkedd, columns = ['Word','Classification'])
        nerTagDF['File_Name'] = fileName
        nerTagDF['Line Key'] = str(i)
        ne = ne.append(nerTagDF) 

oFile.close()
midFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code with indents fixed. You should ensure that your indents are always consistent in your code, and not a mix of spaces and tab characters.

```
ne=pd.DataFrame()

for word in keywordList:    
    for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
        if word in line:
            for l in searchlines[i-3:i+3]: oFile.write(fileName + delim + word + delim +str(i) + delim +str(l)) ## prints Unused MidFile for Reference
            ### Creates normal case line for Named Entity recognition & all Lower Case line for flagging keywords
                #normalCaseLine = str(searchlines[i-3] + searchlines[i-2] + searchlines[i-1] + searchlines[i] + searchlines[i+1] + searchlines[i+2]  + searchlines[i+3]).replace('\n','  ')
            normalCaseLine = searchlines[i-3].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i-1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i].rstrip('\n')  + searchlines[i+1].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+2].rstrip('\n') + searchlines[i+3].rstrip('\n')
            lowerCaseLine = normalCaseLine.lower()
            result = dict((key, len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(sorted(lowerCaseLine.split())))
            ### Get Detail Keywords
            cleanResult = {word: result[word] for word in result if word in detailKeywordList}
            cleanNormLine = normalCaseLine.replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x92s',' ').replace('\x96',' ').replace('\x95',' ')
            ### Enter here if we need to seperate words ex. Tech Keywords

            ner_output = st.tag(str(cleanNormLine).split())
            chunked, pos = [], prev_tag=[], ""

                for i, word_pos in enumerate(ner_output):
                    word, pos = word_pos
                    if pos in ['PERSON', 'ORGANIZATION', 'LOCATION','DATE','MONEY'] and pos == prev_tag:
                            chunked[-1]+=word_pos
                    else:
                                chunked.append(word_pos)
                                prev_tag = pos

            clean_chunkedd = [tuple([" ".join(wordpos[::2]), wordpos[-1]]) if len(wordpos)!=2 else wordpos for wordpos in chunked]

            ### Write Results to Combined file
            midFile.write(fileName+'-'+str(i)+delim+word+delim+str(cleanNormLine)+delim+str(str(cleanResult).split(','))+'\n')
            ### Create NER DataFramez

            nerTagDF =  DataFrame(clean_chunkedd, columns = ['Word','Classification'])
            nerTagDF['File_Name'] = fileName
            nerTagDF['Line Key'] = str(i)
            ne = ne.append(nerTagDF) 

oFile.close()
midFile.close()
```